# Intepretation of hazard times delta t

Tags: survival, hazard

I'm working through J.F. Lawless's 'Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data'. At one point, it's said that:

> In particular, $h(t)\Delta t$ is the approximate probability of death in $[t,t+\Delta t)$, given survival up till $t$

I'm a bit confused by this. I've seen hazard functions (like the Weibull hazard function gamma = 5, below) that clearly have regions where $h(t)\Delta t$ is greater than 1 - this then cannot be a probability. I'm clearly misinterpreting something - any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: $h(t)\Delta t$ is always less than 1 if $\Delta t$ is small enough -- this is an approximation that gets better as $\Delta t$ gets smaller.

Comment: @ThomasLumley I assumed that $h(t)\Delta t$ would just be an approximation of a much more accurate $\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}h(t)$ - that is, the area under the hazard function for some region - but this is clearly larger than 1 so my thinking must be off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hazard rate is the conditional probability density of failure conditional on survival up to the point (sometimes called the "instantaneous" probability density of failure).  If we let $T$ denote the (continuous) time-to-failure then this can be expressed using the limiting definition of a derivative as:

$$h(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{P}(t \leqslant T < t+\Delta t | T \geqslant t)}{\Delta t}.$$

Thus, for sufficiently small $\Delta t$ we have:

$$h(t) \approx \frac{\mathbb{P}(t \leqslant T < t+\Delta t | T \geqslant t)}{\Delta t},$$

and the desired result follows by rearranging this approximating equation.

It may be useful for me to illustrate this approximation and its limits.  To do this, suppose we consider the Weibull distribution with shape parameter $\gamma = 5$ and scale parameter $\lambda = 1$ (with hazard function shown on the fourth plot in your question).

```
#Set parameters
SHAPE <- 5
SCALE <- 1
TIME0 <- 1.00
TIMES <- c(1.05, 1.10, 1.15, 1.20, 1.25)

#Set results table
RESULTS <- data.frame(Time = TIMES,
                      Probability = 0,
                      Approximation = 0)

#Compute exact probabilities of death at times TIMES
#Conditional on survival to time TIME0
for (i in 1:5) {
  RESULTS$Probability[i] <- (pweibull(TIMES[i], shape = SHAPE, scale = SCALE) -
                             pweibull(TIME0, shape = SHAPE, scale = SCALE))/
                            (1 - pweibull(TIME0, shape = SHAPE, scale = SCALE)) }

#Compute approximate probabilities using hazard rate at time TIME0
HAZARD  <- (SCALE^(-SHAPE))*SHAPE*TIME0^(SHAPE-1)
for (i in 1:5) { RESULTS$Approximation[i] <- HAZARD*(TIMES[i] - TIME0) }
#Show results
RESULTS
  Time Probability Approximation
1 1.05   0.2414007          0.25
2 1.10   0.4569262          0.50
3 1.15   0.6362750          0.75
4 1.20   0.7742484          1.00
5 1.25   0.8714912          1.25
```

As you can see, when the time interval $\Delta t$ is small the approximation is reasonably good, but it gets worse as the time interval gets larger.  You can also see that if we take the time interval too large then it is indeed possible to get an approximating probability that is greater than one (though the exact probabilit cannot possibly be greater than one).  This is indeed a danger with this approximation if we take a time interval that is too large.

Comment: I guess what I assume to get from the function is the probability that an event will occur in the next 't time units', given no event so far. Is this something that this function can provide me? If so, how (practically) would I go about calculating this?

Comment: Sorry, edited to correct to conditional probabilities.

Comment: I think what would really help me solidify this is a concrete (though contrived) example. Suppose a patient is standing in front of me, and they want to know "what are the chances that I, and 80 year old, get to live to be 83 years old?" How would I answer this?

Comment: Added example per your request.

Comment: Sorry to be a pill about this, but your example doesn't make sense to me - suppose the hazard function of this individual follows a Weibull hazard function, with gamma = 1 - a constant hazard rate across time. Wouldn't this imply that the probability could be larger than 1? (See figure in my original question, for example)

Comment: I have removed the previous example responding to your comment and I have replaced it with an example from your interest in the Weibull distribution.  Hopefully this explains the situation better.

Comment: Thanks much. I think what I erroneously had it in my head that smaller $\Delta t$ -> more accurate reading over some given time frame - but forgot that the time frame considered is also getting shorter as well.

Comment: Remember that $\Delta t$ is the *length of the time interval* so a small value for this means that you are considering a small time interval (i.e., time point of interest is close to conditioning time).